# I cant get an item from an array for my Discord bot to use to take action

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to program a bot for a server, and I am currently working on making a 'Mute' command. My idea was to make it so when the command is called, the bot must first check if the person has the role which allows them to mute other members, if that condition is met, then the bot would take the second argument, aka the Discord id of the member which must be muted, and give them a role which inhibits them from speaking in the server.

For some reason when I was testing the code, I wasn't able to get past the bot checking whether the second argument was a valid ID for a member of the server.

Here is the `mute` command code:

```js
if (message.member.roles.cache.has('765334017011613717')) {
 console.log('Oh oh');
 const person = message.guild.member(
  message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[1])
 );
 if (!person) {
  console.log('Oh oh 2');
 }
} else message.channel.send('You do not have permission to use this command.');
```

***Note:*** The `console.log()` functions were added so I could see where the problem was happening when running the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things that you might do in order to make this work with the first being more of a suggestion.

First, ideally you always want to check if the role exists and `return` if it doesn't. This prevents you from having to put your entire logic to mute the person into the `if` statement. You do that like this:

```
if (!message.member.roles.cache.has('your role ID')) {
    return message.channel.send('You do not have permission to use this command.');
}
```

The actual problem in your code stems from your way of finding the member. The right way to do that is, either checking the first mention of a member or taking a provided ID from your first argument. Your first argument being not `args[1]` but `args[0]`. If the ID is being used you need to use the `cache` property. [Source](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager)

```
let muteMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
```

You should then check if a member has actually been found and return if not.

```
if (!muteMember) {
    return message.channel.send("That member doesn't exist!")
}
```

*Note: You already have this in your code but I wanted to include it for completeness.*

After that you can continue with your code to mute someone.